# How to extract line from the file on specific condition

Tags: sed, awk

File:

```
chromosome  position  ref  alt 
chr1          1398     A    T 
chr1          2980     A    C 
chr2          3323     C    T,A
chr2          3749     T    G
chr3          5251     C    T,G
chr3          9990     G    C,T
chr4          10345    T    G
```

I need to extract full line when column 4 has 2 or more characters separated by comma

Expected Output is:

```
chr2          3323     C    T,A
chr3          5251     C    T,G
chr3          9990     G    C,T
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of other ways to look at this.

#### Method #1

Since you only are interested in lines if they have more than 2 characters separated by commas you could just `grep` for commas:

```
$ grep "," sample.txt 
chr2          3323     C    T,A
chr3          5251     C    T,G
chr3          9990     G    C,T
```

#### Method #2

You could use `grep`'s PCRE facility. This is where `grep` can use Perl's regular expression engine to do the matching. It's quite powerful and lets you do a lot of what you can do with Perl from `grep`.

*loosely defined*

```
$ grep -P "(\w,)+" sample.txt
```

*strictly defined*

```
$ grep -P '\w+\d\s+\d+\s+\w\s+(\w,)+' sample.txt
```

#### Method #3

Using `awk`. This again is taking advantage of the fact that only the lines with a comma (`,`) are of interest, so it just finds them and prints them:

*loosely defined*

```
$ awk '/,/{print}' sample.txt
```

*more strictly defined*

```
$ awk '/([[:alpha:]])+,[[:alpha:]]/{print}' sample.txt
```

*even more strictly defined*

```
$ awk '$4 ~ /([[:alpha:]])+,[[:alpha:]]/{print}' sample.txt
```

This one looks at the contents of the 4th column and checks that it's a letter followed by a comma, followed by another letter.

*even more strictly defined*

```
$ awk '$4 ~ /([GATC])+,[GATC]/{print}' sample.txt
```

This looks for only a G,A,T, or C followed by a comma, followed by another G,A,T or C.

Comment: @ sim, Thank you for your help on providing 3 methods, in this $ awk '/[[:alpha:]],[[:alpha:]]/{print}' sample.txt ; $ awk '$4 ~ /[[:alpha:]],[[:alpha:]]/{print}' sample.txt ; $ awk '$4 ~ /[GATC],[GATC]/{print}' sample.txt only worked well

Comment: @sara - I've expanded your sample data so that it now includes more than 2 GACT in the 4th column. That's most likely where the issue was coming from. Please try these modified versions with your sample data and let me know if they work as expected.

Comment: @sara - You can't really call out a specific column, you have to use regular expressions to make a pattern that will then selectively match lines that have 2 or more things in the 4th column.

Comment: @sara - for example, `'\w+\d\s+\d+\s+\w\s+(\w,)+'` this says, match a series of word characters (\w+) until you match a series of one digit (\d) until you match a series of spaces (\s+) until you match a series of digits (\d+) etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: @sim - ya sim, i understood it

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ane 'print if($F[3] =~ /^\w,\w/$);' file
```

`-n` tells perl to process the infile one line at a time passing each line to the commands specified in `-e`. The `-a` tells perl to expand each line around the field separator (this defaults to space), and assign this to an array called `@F`. The upshot is for every line we can process it and use `$F[n]` to refer to the nth element of that line.

We then test if field 4 `$F[3]` contains start of string `^`, a word character `\w` followed by a comma and then another word character `\w` and then end of string `$`. If that succeeds we `print` the line.

If those "word characters" are always going to be Cytosine, Adenine, Guanine, and Thymine, you could make it more explicit with:

```
perl -ane 'print if($F[3] =~ /^[GATC],[GATC]$/);' file
```

Comment: @ Drav, Thanks for the one liner code , it works

Answer (score 2):

Another awk solution.

```
awk 'length($4) > 2 && $4 ~ /^([^,],)+[^,]$/' file_name
```

Tested with nawk, will work with gawk too. This will match A,T,G,C,Z,Q,R

Again, if you are just matching ATGC:

```
awk 'length($4) > 2 && $4 ~ /([ATGC],)+[ATGC]/' file_name
```

Comment: i tried with yours script and got the best solution

Answer (score 1):

A simple `awk` one-liner:

```
awk '$4 ~ ","' file
```