# How to remove the comma and print the entire row again for the words which are place after the comma

Tags: linux, sed, awk

File:

```
chr1_156186369  chr1_156186369_A_C,T    A   C,T  33150.29  1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272
chr19_27732257  chr19_27732257_G_C      G   C    262.29    1/2:1,10,7:18:99:414,167
chrM_2619       chrM_2619_A_G,T         A   G,T  33023.29  1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chr9_119375271  chr9_119375271_T_A,G    T   A,G  248.29    1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
```

I need to remove the comma from column 2 and 4 only and print the entire row  for the words which are place after the comma.

Expected output is:

```
chr1_156186369  chr1_156186369_A_C  A   C   33150.29  1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272
chr1_156186369  chr1_156186369_A_T  A   T   33150.29  1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272 
chr19_27732257  chr19_27732257_G_C  G   C   262.29    1/2:1,10,7:18:99:414,167
chrM_2619       chrM_2619_A_G       A   G   33023.29  1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chrM_2619       chrM_2619_A_T       A   T   33023.29  1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chr9_119375271  chr9_119375271_T_A  T   A   248.29    1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
chr9_119375271  chr9_119375271_T_G  T   G   248.29    1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
```

I tried awk but not get any result, also I read the similar type of question here
 [How to extract line from the file on specific condition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90168/how-to-extract-line-from-the-file-on-specific-condition)

Comment: Would be nice to see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with a single command, but it works with this loop in `bash`:

```
cat data.dat | while read line
do
  if echo "${line}" | grep -q '[[:alpha:]],[[:alpha:]]'
  then
    letters=`echo "${line}" | grep -o '[[:alpha:]],[[:alpha:]]' | head -n 1`
    for letter in `echo ${letters} | sed 's/,/ /g'`
    do
      echo "${line}" | sed 's/'"${letters}"'/'"${letter}"'  /g'
    done
  else
    echo "${line}"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk '{
  split ($2,w2,",");
  split ($4,w4,",");
  for (i in w4) {
    print $1,substr(w2[1],0,length(w2[1])-length(w4[i])) w4[i],$3,w4[i],$5,$6;
  }}'
```

Note there is no error handling in case the values after comma are not equal for column 2 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` assuming the single character separated values like `C,T` are repeated

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.*)([A-Z]),([A-Z])(.*)\2,\3(.*)/\1\2\4\2\5\n\1\3\4\3\5/' ip.txt 
chr1_156186369  chr1_156186369_A_C    A   C  33150.29  1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272
chr1_156186369  chr1_156186369_A_T    A   T  33150.29  1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272
chr19_27732257  chr19_27732257_G_C      G   C    262.29    1/2:1,10,7:18:99:414,167
chrM_2619       chrM_2619_A_G         A   G  33023.29  1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chrM_2619       chrM_2619_A_T         A   T  33023.29  1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chr9_119375271  chr9_119375271_T_A    T   A  248.29    1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
chr9_119375271  chr9_119375271_T_G    T   G  248.29    1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
```

- `^(.*)` starting text
- `([A-Z]),([A-Z])` comma separated single characters
- `(.*)` text in between the repetition
- `\2,\3` match the comma separated single characters again
- `(.*)` rest of line
- `\1\2\4\2\5\n\1\3\4\3\5` required output format
- Note that spacing doesn't exactly match with expected output

Comment: your one line code is awesome, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Split the 4th field on the comma and use the slices in that column, as well as to replace the last `_X,Y` into `_slice`, if there are any:

```
awk '{
      n=split($4,slices,",")
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        res=$2
        sub(/.,.*/,slices[i],res)
        print $1, res, $3, slices[i], $5, $6
      }
     }' file
```

I don't like very much how I print the fields, since I do indicate from the 1st to the 6th, so hopefully this is static.

```
$ awk '{n=split($4,slices,","); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {res=$2; sub(/.,.*/,slices[i],res); print $1, res, $3, slices[i], $5, $6}}' a
chr1_156186369 chr1_156186369_A_C A C 33150.29 1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272
chr1_156186369 chr1_156186369_A_T A T 33150.29 1/2:0,4,6:10:88:272
chr19_27732257 chr19_27732257_G_C G C 262.29 1/2:1,10,7:18:99:414,167
chrM_2619 chrM_2619_A_G A G 33023.29 1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chrM_2619 chrM_2619_A_T A T 33023.29 1/2:0,5,5:10:99:293,144,129
chr9_119375271 chr9_119375271_T_A T A 248.29 1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
chr9_119375271 chr9_119375271_T_G T G 248.29 1/2:1,11,5:17:99:359,107,113
```